# AJAX POST does not work

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I can not get my code working. I want to send the contents of the 'next_question_id' button to my php file next_question.php. And then show the output in the div "question_text". What am I doing wrong.. :)

**Javascript**

```js
  function myFunction(clicked_id) {
    var button = clicked_id
    var next_question_id = document.getElementById(button).getAttribute("next_question_id");
    $.post('next_question.php', {
        postnextquestionid: next_question_id
      },
      function(data) {
        $('#question_text').html(data);
      });

  }
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$next_question_id = $_POST['next_question_id'];
echo $next_question_id;
?>
```

Comment: What "does not work" means? What do you expect? What error message do you have?

Comment: next_question_id != postnextquestionid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your post var would be `postnextquestionid`, not  `next_question_id`

```
$next_question_id = $_POST['postnextquestionid'];
```

Comment: Exactly as @vlscanner said.

Comment: Thnx @vlscanner